# Combine MySQLi rows and add counter?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I've quote a simple database collecting simple information. There is a high chance of creating identical entries.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO track_table (sitename, affiliate, refferal) values ('$sitename', '$affiliate', '$refferal')";
```

on a separate page, I pull a report

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT sitename, affiliate, refferal FROM track_table") 
    or die("Problem executing query.");
    print "<table border=1>\n";
    print "<tr><td><b>SITENAME</b></td><td><b>AFFILIATE</b></td><td><b>REFFERAL</b></td></tr>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        echo "<td>", $row['sitename'], "</td><td>", $row['affiliate'], "</td><td>", $row['refferal'], "</td></tr>\n"; 
    }
echo "</table>\n";
```

This outputs

```
SITENAME ------------ AFFILIATE ------------- REFFERAL

foo.com ---------------12345------------------bar.com

foo.com ---------------12345------------------bar.com

abc.com ---------------98765------------------xyz.com
```

as  you can see, I can have 2 identical entries. Is there a way I can calculate 1 and 2 being the exact same, so not showing them, but perhaps in a new col that shows (2)

```
SITENAME ------------ AFFILIATE ------------- REFFERAL-------COUNT

foo.com ---------------12345------------------bar.com---------(2)

abc.com ---------------98765------------------xyz.com---------(1)
```

Comment: The usual spelling of [referral](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/referral) is with one f.

Comment: I'm aware of that. It was a typo I began with and will end up changing as soon as I get that table working. Thanks for the obvs. though ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GROUP BY:

```
SELECT sitename, affiliate, refferal, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM track_table
GROUP BY sitename, affiliate, refferal
```

If you don't need the count column then you could use `SELECT DISTINCT` instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sitename, affiliate, refferal
FROM track_table
```

Comment: Beautiful. Absolutely beautiful. Thanks very much works like a charm :) - I'll accept it in 6 mins when it lets me ^^

Answer (score 1):

Add a unique key on your 2 columns, and change your query into :

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO
```

And at the creation add a validator that will check that the values that you want to insert don't exists in your table.